# dynamic array member variables

Tags: c++

Hey i'm new to c++ and still working out its perticularities.  I'm having the darnedest time trying to figure out whats going wrong with this code.  I've stepped through it and everything is calculating correctly.  The issue is that value_array in the base class doesn't seem to be retaining the values once the derived class Calculate function ends.  I think i've declared and allocated the array properly.  I'm stumped...

```
#include <iostream>

class Indicator 
{
protected:
    double * value_array;
    double * input_array;
    int input_size;
public:
    Indicator(double input[], int size) 
    { 
        input_array = input; 
        input_size = size; 
        value_array = new double[size]; // issue with value_array
    }
    double operator[] (int index) { return value_array[index]; }
    void virtual Calculate() {}
    ~Indicator() { delete[] value_array; }
};

class SMA : public Indicator 
{
private:
    int nperiod;
    double sum;
public:
    SMA(double input[], int size, int period) : Indicator(input, size) 
    { 
        nperiod = period; 
        sum = 0; 
        Calculate(); 
    }
    void Calculate();
};

void SMA::Calculate()
{ 
    for (int i=0; i<input_size; i++)
    {
        if (i > nperiod - 1) 
        {
            sum += input_array[i] - input_array[i-nperiod];
            value_array[i] = sum / nperiod;
        }
        else
        {
            sum += input_array[i];
            value_array[i] = sum / (i+1);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    double input[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    Indicator indicator = SMA(input,10,5);

    double value = indicator[0];
    std::cout << "value: " << value << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    exit(0);
}
```

#### Update:

Here is the code implemented with vectors.  I wanted to leave the input as double[] to be consistent with other libraries, any other potential issues I should be aware of?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Indicator 
{
protected:
    std::vector<double> value_vector;
    double * input_array;
    int input_size;
public:
    Indicator(double input[], int size) 
    { 
        input_array = input; 
        input_size = size; 
        value_vector.reserve(size);
    }
    double operator[] (int index) { return value_vector[index]; }
    void virtual Calculate() {}
};

class SMA : public Indicator 
{
private:
    int nperiod;
    double sum;
public:
    SMA(double input[], int size, int period) : Indicator(input, size) 
    { 
        nperiod = period; 
        sum = 0; 
        Calculate(); 
    }
    void Calculate();
};

void SMA::Calculate()
{ 
    for (int i=0; i<input_size; i++)
    {
        if (i > nperiod - 1) 
        {
            sum += input_array[i] - input_array[i-nperiod];
            value_vector.push_back(sum / nperiod);
        }
        else
        {
            sum += input_array[i];
            value_vector.push_back(sum / (i+1));
        }
        std::cout << "sma:  " << value_vector[i] << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    double input[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    Indicator indicator = SMA(input,10,5);

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "main: " << indicator[i] << std::endl;
    }

    std::cin.get();
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Although a useful exercise for education, please use a `std::vector` in real code.

Comment: @delnan care to explain why not? maybe a link explaining the problems and solutions

Comment: "virtual" is on the wrong place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're violating the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/). Since your class manages a resource, it needs a copy constructor and an assignment operator. I strongly suggest replacing any `T*` data member with a `std::vector<T>` data member. Then you don't need to write those special member functions manually.

Answer (score 2):

Hia,

a few things are wrong.

As FredOverflow says you need a copy constructor and assignment, something like:

```
Indicator::Indicator(const Indicator& other)
{
  input_size = other.input_size;

  //direct copy of reference as indicator doesn't own this data
  //Note a shared pointer (such as boost::shared_ptr) would be better than a naked reference
  input_array = other.input_array; 
  //construct a new set of data
  value_array = new double[input_size]; 
  //do you want to copy the data too? maybe a memcpy follows?
  memcpy(value_array, other.value_array, input_size*sizeof(double));
}
```

Then you need an assignment

```
Indicator&
Indicator::operator=(const Indicator& other)
{
  //make sure you are not assigning itself
  if(this != &other)
  {
    input_size = other.input_size;

    //direct copy of reference as indicator doesn't own this data
    //Note a shared pointer (such as boost::shared_ptr) would be better than a naked reference
    input_array = other.input_array; 
    //destroy old data and construct a new set of data
    delete[] value_array;
    value_array = new double[input_size]; 
    //do you want to copy the data too? maybe a memcpy follows?
    memcpy(value_array, other.value_array, input_size*sizeof(double));
  }
  return *this;
}
```

You probably also want to make the destructor virtual - see  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors) for why - 
it helps prevent memory leaks in the destructor of SMA

```
virtual ~Indicator() { delete[] value_array; }
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, was wondering how it could be implmented with double *.  Coming from a managed c background I never realized how much c#/java handles for you :P

Comment: @user615174 Not sure what you mean?  This is with the double* as in your original question.  The other answers tell you to use a vector because they handle the deletes & reasignments (done above) that you need because you are copying a pointer to an array.  The default copy and assignment operators would work if you used std::vector. They don't work with a double because you want to manage memory.

Answer (score 0):

Use **`std::vector`** instead of raw arrays.

`std::vector` handles all the memory management and copying and so forth.

Cheers & hth.,